# Did Benjamin recognize Joseph when he came down to Egypt

Tags: yosef, genesis-bereishith, chumash

The Torah mentions that Yosef recognized his brothers but they didn't recognize him ([Bereshit 42:7-8](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.42.7-8)).
Was wondering whether any commentaries deal with the question of when Benjamin came down did he or did he not recognize Yosef right away and whether he kept it secret?
Potentially 2 reasons

- Benjamin believed in Yosef he named his 10 sons after Yosef.
  His brothers doubted Yosef's fate they from Rashi at least really believed that Yosef was in prison somewhere. They were really shocked when Yosef revealed themselves to him and particularly as viceroy of Egypt.
- Second Joseph's dreams, which his brothers dismissed but their father took seriously, could have further contributed to Benjamin's faith in him.

Thanks

Comment: Why would he recognize Yosef more than the brothers? If anything he is less likely to recognize him, as he was younger when they parted ways.

Comment: Hi, two reasons Benjamin believed in Yosef he named his 10 sons after Yosef. 
His brothers doubted Yosef's fate they from Rashi at least really believed that Yosef was in prison somewhere. They were really shocked when Yosef revealed themselves to him and particularly as viceroy of Egypt.  
Second Joseph's dreams, which his brothers dismissed but their father took seriously, could have further contributed to Benjamin's faith in him.

Comment: The pasuk you quoted answers your question. The brothers did not recognize him

Comment: Benamin wasnt with them at that point he only came down later.

Answer (score 2):

Rashi ([Bereishis 43:30](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.43.30.1?lang=he)) relates that when Yosef asked Binyamin, "Do you have a maternal brother?" he replied, "I had a brother, but I don't know where he is." That pretty clearly indicates he didn't recognize Yosef.

[Sefer Hayashar](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaYashar_(midrash)%2C_Book_of_Genesis%2C_Miketz.22?lang=he) has Binyamin using astrology to divine that Yosef was there but not understanding how this could be so, and Yosef then disclosing his identity to Binyamin. That too shows that Binyamin didn't recognize him.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen anyone discussing this. But it is likely that he didn't, otherwise he would have told his brothers so, especially after the cup was found in his bag.

Comment: On the contrary, if he had recognized Yosef he'd have known he wasn't in real trouble and may have let the plan play itself out.

Comment: And let Yehuda put himself in danger????????????

Comment: Danger of what? Yosef wasn't going to do anything.

Comment: Any of his soldiers could have easily tried to kill him for his affront to the viceroy. This was before Yosef sent them all out.